# What is the difference between definition and explanation?

Tags: meaning, differences

What is the difference between definition and explanation? 
According to definition of both:

Explanation: A statement or account that makes something clear.

Definition:  A statement of the exact meaning of a word, especially in a dictionary

Are both are the synonym of each other and can replace each other in ans or not?

Comment: Hi @Haziq, good questions are those that show some digging or research by the questioner. You might include the dictionary definitions of both words and then specifically ask for some subtlety you have doubts about.

Comment: @Pablo Straub I have edit the question and added the definition now  for more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Definition** is *a statement expressing the **essential nature** of something* ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/definition)).

Definition of something tells you "what that is, what's its essence."

> A car can be defined as a wheeled motor vehicle used for transportation, primarily on roads, which usually seats one to eight people, has four tires, and mainly transports people rather than goods.

**Explanation** is *a statement made to clarify something and **make it understandable*** ([Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/explanation?s=t)).

Explanation is a broader term than definition; it describes in more detail how something works.

> Here is an explanation of how a car works: A car uses energy, usually
>   by combustion of a liquid fuel or from a battery, which is used to
>   move the wheels, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A definition is a factual based meaning for something whereas an explanation is a statement which makes something clear.

For example, you could define what something is however, without explanation it is meaningless without context.

Comment: Please add a source to support your answer.